# KVM is installed and KVM acceleration can be used but AVD is still throwing the same error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, kvm

Im using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit and Android studio 2.1 running on intel corei3 3rd gen, I have installed KVM and checked it using `$kvm-ok` and it showed `INFO: /dev/kvm exists KVM acceleration can be used` , so its working fine.
The thing is when I open Android Studio and AVD manager its saying [Screenshot-click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBfXO.png) , even though its already installed.

I tried the arm version thinkinh that would work without KVM but that too isn't working, it says in the log
`/home/ajmal/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: 1: /home/ajmal/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Please Help

Comment: Make sure that processor support Intel virtualization or not

Comment: it does, I enabled it through my bios and also checked through the terminal if it supports it.

Comment: Have u installed HAXM on your machine

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, intel doesn't have HAXM for ubuntu, they have KVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed Ubuntu 32bit and installed 64bit and tried the same, everything worked like a charm.